# wildfly loading class from wrong jar

Tags: jar, wildfly

I am deploying my war file on Wildfly 9

I am getting exception which is quite strange.

> 17:40:27,952 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-7) UT005023:
>   Exception handling request to /DirectRegistry/index.htm:
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler
>   processing fai led; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletInputStream
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:860)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:755)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:396)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:350)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
>           at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
>           at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletInputStream
>           at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.isMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:110)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:937)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:797)
>           ... 34 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletInputStream >from [Module
>   "org.apache.commons-fileupload:main" from local module loader
>   @6c3a6465 (finder: local module finder @6d955a6 5 (roots:
>   C:\JAVA\WF9\wildfly-9.0.0.Final\modules,C:\JAVA\WF9\wildfly-9.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
>           ... 37 more

My jboss-deployment structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <!--
            we want to use the saaj module provided by JBoss
            it looks like we can't use the implementation provided by the JDK - JBoss somehow does not seem to allow it
            -->
            <module name="com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj" />
            <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
            <module name="com.gbst.directregistry.configuration" />
            <module name="com.gbst.directregistry.hypersonic" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons-fileupload"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

javax.servlet.api in the service/layers/... is where it is located and I have seen that the class is located there.

org.apache.commons-fileupload is something I made myself to contain a class to solve an issue when i had this:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
     class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

seems like this CommonsMultipartResolver uses : org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUpload which is not found in the system/layer/.. libs so i added my own lib in module\org\apache\commons-fileupload . Every time i try to invoke my url now it throws the error above. Why is WF trying to find ServletInputStream in org.apache.commons-fileupload even though it is already there in the WF System/layers/ libs even though it is located in javax.servlet.api. This is base libraries for WF so these should ahve precedence.
as for the commons-fileupload.jar is concerned it doesnt not have any Javax package. so i am not sure why is it looking into this jar.

Appreciate any insight.

Comment: What is the `org.apache.commons-fileupload`? It looks like it has a dependency on a the servlet API. If that's the case then the module you created needs a dependency on the servlet API.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins that solved it. Thanks